# How to calculate only integer types in array?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
class Distance {
private String name;
private int dist;
public Distance(String name, int dist) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dist = dist;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getDist() {
    return dist;
}
public void setDist(int dist) {
    this.dist = dist;
}
public String toString() {
    return "Distance [name=" + name + ", school street=" + dist + "]";
}
}
class DistanceComp {
public static Distance longdistance(Distance[] dim) {
    Distance max = dim[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < dim.length; i++) {
        if (max.getDist() < dim[i].getDist())
            max = dim[i];
    }
    return max;
}
public static Distance shortdistance(Distance[] dim) {
    Distance min = dim[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < dim.length; i++) {
        if (min.getDist() > dim[i].getDist())
            min = dim[i];
    }
    return min;
}
}
public class week03_01 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Distance[] dist = new Distance[3];
    System.out.print(">> how many students? : ");
    int num = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.print(">> name and distance : ");
        dist[i] = new Distance(in.next(), in.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println("\na student with the longest commute to school : " + DistanceComp.longdistance(dist));
    System.out.println("a student with the shortest commute to school  : " + DistanceComp.shortdistance(dist));
    System.out.println("school distance difference is " + );
}
}
```

I also want to print the "shool distance differecnce".
but it doesn't calculate. i think it has String types.

I think calculate only integer types in an array, but i don't know the code.

Or is s there any other way? Ask for advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't calculate"?

Comment: DistanceComp.longdistance(dist) - DistanceComp.shortdistance(dist)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

In your `DistanceComp` class, create a method to subtract two Distances similar like you did for `longdistance` and `shortdistance`:

```
    public static int subtractDistance(Distance dist1, Distance dist2) {
        int difference = Math.abs(dist1.getDist() - dist2.getDist());
        return difference;
    }
```

Then, use that in your `System.out`:

```
System.out.println("school distance difference is " + DistanceComp.subtractDistance(DistanceComp.longdistance(dist),  DistanceComp.shortdistance(dist)));
```

Some notes fyi:

1. Your code currently only works with 3 students.
2. Instead of using long names, assign them to a shorter-named variable. This helps with code readability.